# Is this mention of the double-slit phenomenon broadly correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, measurement-problem

I'm reading a book of philosophy (Less Than Nothing by Slavoj Žižek) and a chapter in it (called The Ontology of Quantum Mechanics) frequently references the double-slit phenomenon. At one point it says the following three points:

> (1) Even if we shoot the electrons individually, one after the other,
>   they will, if we do not measure their path, form a wave pattern―but
>   how can they? With what does each individual electron interact? (With
>   itself.)
>
> (2) Even if we measure (or not) the path after the electrons have
>   already passed through the slits, the pattern still depends on our
>   measurement―but how can it, when the measurement takes place after the
>   passage through the slit? It seems as though we can retroactively
>   change the past.
>
> (3) Even if we do not enact measurement at all, the mere fact that the
>   measurement apparatus (and, with it, the possibility of measurement)
>   is there makes the electron behave as a particle―but how can it, when
>   it was in no way affected by the measurement apparatus?

While I'm studying biophysics and I've done a course on elementary atomic physics and QM, I'm far from being qualified to tell whether these claims are problematic or not, and if they are indeed problematic, in what ways. Of course I'm not looking for an in-depth analysis, I'd just be glad if someone pointed out if there are fundamental and obvious misunderstandings contained in the quoted passage.

I'm especially suspicious about the third point - from my studies I would think that the mere *presence* of a measuring apparatus is irrelevant, what matters is the physical act of measurement and the perturbations it involve.

Comment: Is it even remotely correct? No, it's not even remotely correct. Electrons aren't particles but quanta of a quantum field. What you are reading there are the desperate attempts to make sense of a particle picture in the 1920s. By 1929 it was understood in broad terms why it's not necessary and by the mid 1930s the smarter physicists had moved on to sorting out relativistic quantum field theory. That is the correct framework to deal with all of these phenomena in a self-consistent way and it basically puts away with particles completely. It's turtles riding quantum waves all the way down.

Comment: I am curious as to how many others on this site have also given up on the particle theory and rely only on quantum Field theory for answers. Are you saying that electrons are not physically there? I have also heard you make similar statements about photons. Could you please explain this a little clearer. If so many smart physicists have really given up on particles then maybe that's why many other physicist think we have been at a dead  in for a long time.

Comment: @BillAlsept: An electron is physically "there", if you mean that "it's there where you measure it". From that it does NOT automatically follow that it's a physical thing that is also in a defined position at all other times when you do not measure it. That is exactly the big lesson to be learned that differentiates quantum mechanics from classical mechanics. In CM we can make that step, in QM we can't. And that's OK, because in QM "the field" is still always there. We do have an entity that has an existence ontology. It's just everywhere all the time instead of being "here some of the time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an answer by an experimental physicist.

Quantum mechanics started with the wave equation of Schrodinger and then the relativistic covariant ones of Dirac and Klein-Gordon. These describe single particles in potential wells and the solutions are called wave functions and their complex conjugate square gives the probability of observation/interaction/decay for given boundary conditions. This is the basic quantum mechanical framework, usually called first quantization. In this framework electrons, atoms   and molecules are quantum mechanical entities, described by the wavefunction. When measured they have particle type properties, i.e. an individual (x,y,z,t) location . Collectively they display  the wave nature of the wavefunction.

Lets take the statements one at a time:

> (1) Even if we shoot the electrons individually, one after the other, they will, if we do not measure their path, form a wave pattern―but how can they? With what does each individual electron interact? (With itself.)

The electron does not interact with itself, it is described by the boundary conditions set up by the slit which will define the wavefunction and thus the  probability wave  that describes its behavior. [Here is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) a single electron at a time:

[image: doubleslit]

> Electron buildup over time

Each individual electron ends up as a spot on the screen, in its particle like aspect. The accumulation of electrons with the same slits ( boundary conditions) shows the probability distributions which has a wave pattern.

> (2) Even if we measure (or not) the path after the electrons have already passed through the slits, the pattern still depends on our measurement―but how can it, when the measurement takes place after the passage through the slit? It seems as though we can retroactively change the past.

This is confusing . The screen can be up to the slits , the screen is a measurement and the pattern's widths will depend on the location of the screen , not the interference pattern which will be there. Only if a measurement apparatus is placed at the slits or on the way it will change the boundary conditions and thus the solution, and the pattern will be destroyed ( see 3).

> (3) Even if we do not enact measurement at all, the mere fact that the measurement apparatus (and, with it, the possibility of measurement) is there makes the electron behave as a particle―but how can it, when it was in no way affected by the measurement apparatus?

This is confusing, it might be discussing a which slit passage detection. This by construction changes the boundary conditions of the problem . Changed boundary conditions will give different results and randomize the pattern. It is no longer the same problem. Also he is using "particle" pattern as classical, billiard ball particle which is not really true

This [recent paper](http://phys.org/news/2011-01-which-way-detector-mystery-double-slit.html) clears this type of confusion:

> Overall, the results suggest that the type of scattering an electron undergoes determines the mark it leaves on the back wall, and that a detector at one of the slits can change the type of scattering. The physicists concluded that, while elastically scattered electrons can cause an interference pattern, the inelastically scattered electrons do not contribute to the interference process.

Comment: I have a problem with the linked paper you cite - the presence of a detector at a single slit is enough to destroy interference, even if the detector is not triggered; i.e. the subset of marks on the screen not correlated with a slit detection click does not produce fringes.   No click at the slit = no interaction, meaning the electron should still be able to elastically scatter and contribute to interference according to their interpretation, which is not what we see experimentally.

Comment: I may be missing how this differs from the "no click" detector subset, I'll re-read the paper again but it seems analogous

Comment: I built an ultrafast photo-electron diffractometer during my doctoral research; I did many, many electron diffraction experiments, and can note the following: when detected, there is always one spot; if you let the system accumulate, a diffraction pattern appears.  When the electrons are generated, the photo-electric effect emits electrons one-by-one. In some runs the electron bunches were very small, statistically there was one electron at a time passing through the ultrathin gold film.  Particle-wave-particle is how it appears to the experimentalist.

Comment: @JamesPattarini i deleted my previous comment because it was mixing up things.  The way I understand it is that the electrons that interacted with the filter had a pattern of a point source the ones that went through kept the coherence of the original beam.

Comment: @PeterDiehr: Do you know Mott's 1929 paper "The wave mechanics of α-ray tracks"? It explains why "particles" seem to appear in wave mechanics. Today it can be reproduced in general with weak measurement theory and decoherence. Particles are of no use and of no need in quantum mechanics and we understood this very early, it's just one of those flukes of science history that "the news" never made it into the classroom.

Comment: @CuriousOne  Many people have the illusion that once a successful mathematical model is built, it is reality.  History of physics shows that this is not true up to now and there is no reason to believe that the present most advanced model is really really reality. Not to forget also that at the heart of this "particles are no use" model, the Lagrangians, point particles with masses are used to get the basis of QFT.  My position is that the appropriate , mathematically correct, model should be used for the appropriate framework under study/question, and in answers, the clearest for the OP.

Comment: @PeterDiehr the above comment might interest you.

Comment: @annav: The notion of particle is VERY well defined in classical mechanics. It's not a fundamental property of matter but, as you can find in the very first sentence of Landau Lifshitz Volume I an approximation. A planet can be "a particle" and have a well defined point Lagrangian. We call that the Kepler problem even though we know that a planet is anything but small and that it has many more properties than just the trajectory of its center of mass. Please, everyone, stop denying the most simple definitions of classical mechanics to keep this ridiculous idea of point particles alive. Please.

Comment: @CuriousOne surely if they stop putting it in the standard model lagrangian I will stop using it in scattering crossections etc, since it will no  longer be the correct model. I am all for strings after all  :).

Comment: @annav: Do not mistake the one particle toy "standard Lagrangian" that you remember from your first theory classes for "standard physics".  The Lagrange formalism has absolutely no preference for the number of degrees of freedom and it can be used just as nicely with a density to describe conservative continuum mechanics problems. The standard model is an epicycle theory that has absolutely nothing to do with fundamental physics. You, of all people, should know that. Having said that... the standard model describes fields, not particles. You should know that, too.

Comment: @CuriousOne  We disagree on this. I have discussed it with theorists, and the ground state of all field theories has to be a solution of  a quantum mechanical equation for that field, i.e. an electron for the electron field, and an electron has a mass and is a point particle in the equation. One can then create a field theory on these ground state functions operating with creation and annihilation operators. Note, I am not saying electrons exist as point particles, they are quantum mechanical entities,  expressed as four dimensional points when measured and represented by probability waves.

Comment: @annav: The equations of QFT are the equations of a field theory. The ground state of a field theory is not "one particle". That's already an excited state for which you need a source. For bosons you can excite an arbitrary number of them at every spacetime point, for fermions you can excite, at most, two. Or you can excite none. In thermodynamic equilibrium the particle number is not even defined, even though the field state is defined. Any which way you turn this thing, the particle picture is naive and unproductive. We call it quantum mechanics and quantum field theory for good reason.

Comment: @CuriousOne you need a ground state wave function  to operate on and to set up the intergrals to calculate is all I am saying, that has the mass of the electron there and that it is a point particle.  The whole QFT fuss is so as to calculate the probability distributions, not to play with mathematics.

Comment: Here is an analogy. A fourier series has all relevant sines and cosines and can fit arbitrary angular distributions. That does not mean that the sine and the cosine cannot be  a distribution by itself, of a much simpler set up. If the setup is simple, no need for fourier series expressions to complicate simple issues

Comment: @annav: The ground state wave function in a field theory is not "one particle". Your detector does not always measure at least one electron, does it? If you want an electron in a volume, you have to supply an electron. It's not already in there. If you supply an electron, you are not supplying it in a particle state. You can do that by giving it a high energy/momentum, which is what high energy physics does, but that's not the most general state of the theory. That just happens to be the states that YOU are familiar with because you always work with high momentum states.

Comment: @annav: That is exactly what Mott was trying to explain to you in 1929. Today it's 2016. We are 87 years later... I think that's enough time to read and internalize a paper with six pages and trivial math. Particle tracks are not particles. They are a secondary phenomenon that is triggered by the physics of the detector. Take the detector away, there are no tracks, just a field. No points, just an operator valued field. Is that strange? Yes. Can we get over that it's strange? Yes, we can get over it and move on without the Newtonian toy models.

Comment: Please  understand that I understand what you are saying, but you do not understand what I am saying: that everything is a model, including QFT, and one should utilize the appropriate model to the problem and to the question's level. After all we live in a newtonian world as far as our five senses tell us,  and we start our modeling from there. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Even if we shoot the electrons individually, one after the other, they will, if we do not measure their path, form a wave pattern―but how can they? With what does each individual electron interact? (With itself.)

The way to work out what's happening is to try to guess what's happening and then look for ways to rule out guesses. Suppose a single electron goes through just one slit and there's nothing else going on. At any given point on the screen, if you open up another slit, then that point should see more electrons because you've let in electrons that otherwise would not have come into the experiment. But you don't see that: rather, you can have fewer electrons at a particular point when the slit is open. So every time you detect an electron there was something going through both slits. If you put a detector in front of both slits, only one will go off at any given time, so the electron doesn't split into two parts, each of which goes through one slit. Nevertheless whatever is going through the slits behaves just like an electron: it can be deflected by magnets etc. So there are two versions of the same electron and they interfere with one another. See "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch, Chapter 2 for a clearer explanation.

> (2) Even if we measure (or not) the path after the electrons have already passed through the slits, the pattern still depends on our measurement―but how can it, when the measurement takes place after the passage through the slit? It seems as though we can retroactively change the past.
>
> (3) Even if we do not enact measurement at all, the mere fact that the measurement apparatus (and, with it, the possibility of measurement) is there makes the electron behave as a particle―but how can it, when it was in no way affected by the measurement apparatus?

No. There are two versions of the electron, one going through each slit. Both versions contribute to the outcome of the experiment. Now, when the electron version going through the other slit comes to the place where you put the detector, it interacts with something that acts exactly like the detector. For example, if the detector blocked some particular subset of the electron's possible paths, that set would no longer contribute to the interference. But you don't see the detector go off, so there is another version of the detector that went off in response to the presence of the electron.

See

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9305002.

Comment: Electrons are not particles. You really have to let go of this illusion. It's like asking the question "How do I make epicycles work better?" eighty years after Kepler had found the correct solution. Really.